# Bash shift changes expected value of associative array

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, command

I made a simple script, that matches the positional arguments starting with dash, and saves them into an associative array.

```bash
declare -A opts

for i; do
  [[ "$i" =~ - ]] && opts[$i]=1
done

shift "${#opts[*]}"

echo "opts: ${opts[*]}"
echo "!opts: ${!opts[-d]}"
echo "Query: $*"
```

For the call `./script -d hello world` the output is:

```
opts: 1
!opts: hello
Query: hello world
```

Which is unexpected, since the key of `${!opts[-d]}` is supposed to be `-d` itself if defined. This behavior happens because of the shift command, when it is removed from the code, the output is as expected:

```
opts: 1
!opts: -d
Query: -d hello world
```

Why does shift interfere with the created associative array?

Comment: This method of handling options seems really janky. Suppose you ran `./script ArgOne Arg-Two`: it'd set `opts[Arg-Two]=1`, and shift `ArgOne` off the argument list (leaving `Arg-Two` there).

Comment: This was the first time I saw `for i; do` ... is this shorthand documented somewhere, or how did you stumble upon it?

Comment: It's in the manpage

`The  list of words following in is expanded, generating a list of items.  The variable name is set to each element of this list in turn, and list is executed each time.  If the in word is omitted, the for command executes list once for each  positional parameter that is set (see PARAMETERS below).` In this case `word` is what you would put after `in`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The associative array isn't being changed; you can verify this by putting a `declare -p opts` after the `shift`, which will give

```bash
declare -A opts=([-d]="1" )
```

The problem: `${!opts[-d]}` doesn't do what you seem to expect. First, `opts[-d]` is looked up, which is the value `1`. Then  the `!` means that's used as the *name* of a variable to substitute - so it's effectively the same as $1, which, after the `shift`, is `hello`.

If you want to print out all the keys of the associative array, use `${!opts[@]}`. The leading `!` has two different meanings in `bash` paramater expansion depending on if used with an array with `@` or `*` in the brackets, or an index/normal variables.